# Ruby on Rails - Re-usable Select item page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm pretty new with Ruby on Rails. I have done tutorials and an online class. I know enough to have my way around the development environment, to create tables, controllers, views etc. However, the classes and tutorials don't really show you in depth things you may have to work with in a real software development situation.

I'm in the process of converting a piece of software to the Ruby on Rails platform. Here is the situation. I have a Salesman controller that has salesman information. Then i have a client controller that handles client information. A salesman has many clients and clients have one salesman. I already coded the REST architecture for the Salesman object. Now, i have to create the client. But before i can get to the new action in the controller, i have to select a salesman first. This select salesman page is going to be needed on many other occasions as i will have other controllers such as commissions , purchase orders etc that have to be tied to a salesman first. How do i proceed to code such a "temporary select" page before actually going to the new action in the controller. Can we define custom actions after which i would just redirect_to the new action passing the salesman id as a param?

Comment: Put that piece of code in a **partial** and render. Partial files are exactly used for this purpose.

Comment: Ok, but how do i go about the sequence of events. The "Add new client" item in my navigation should go where? Right now it goes to the new_accountant route. Which in turns executes the new action in the client controller. Where does the partial get called/rendered? And then how do i pass the selected salesman to the new or create action?

Answer (score 0):

You need to design the app similar to a multi-tenant app. In your case, Sales Person is like a tenant.

Here is the conceptual design:

1. add current_id **class** attribute to SalesMan

   `cattr_accessor :current_id, instance_writer: false, instance_reader: false`
2. In all your models that belong to a sales person, define the default scope:

   `default_scope { where(sales_man_id: SalesMan.current_id) }`
3. Ensure that current sales man is set before executing any actions that depend on sales man being pre-selected. There are multiple approaches for achieving this and it also depends what kind of user experience you want to provide. Couple of options:

   1. Only show the navs such as New Client only if a salesman is pre-selected. Provide a menu option to select a salesman. In that action set SalesMan.current_id.
   2. If the salesman is going to be different across many subsequent transactions, you may want to implement a salesman selection (step 1 of workflow) through a controller before action. For example, when user selects New Client nav option, the before action can redirect to sales man selection and set a flag. SalesMan controllers selected action should redirect to New Client action and ensure that proper flags (parameters) are set to avoid cycles. Define a new controller SalesManSelectionController and subclass all the controllers whose models depend on salesman.

Comment: The multi tenant app (from what i could read) appears to be a bit too sophisticated for what i want to do. The solution i am looking for is the  one where i would want to have a salesman selection process ( list that can be sorted and filtered) before any new action from a controller that  needs to set a salesman first. From what i understand, i need to wirte a before_action in the client controller such as:  before_action :select_salesman, only: [:new].  Question is.. where is that select_salesman method coming from? Where do i write it? In a helper? in one of the controllers?

Comment: Sorry about the layout of my comments. I have yet to master the tags that would make my comments showing up with line breaks etc

Comment: Can you elaborate on salesman selection. Is it as simple as selecting a person by name from a dropdown select box? if it is then you simply include that in your forms where a salesman should be selected.

Comment: And it all depends on the workflow of your app. Here is another approach but not sure if it fits your needs:   Lets says a salesman has to be selected before 1. New Client and 2. New Commission   define a route for salesman selection (Select action) and implement select action in controller and of course the view. But in the nav options of new client and new commission, specify the route to Salesman Select with new_client or new_commission as parameters. Lets call it forward_action.  In the salesman controller, in select action, redirect to corresponding path along with salesman id.

Comment: The Select Salesman page would be an html page, like a list, that is sortable and searchable. I guess i could use a dropdown as well in the forms, but it would have to be dynamically searchable. The users are used to go over the "Select Salesman" page before getting to the actual data entry form and then have the salesman information pre-filled from the selected Salesman id.

Comment: So in that second solution, i create a Select action for the Salesman controller. Then i call the Select action from the navigation and pass a parameter whether i want to redirect to the new client form or new commission form following the selec action in the Salesman controller?